# jenkins upload file to artifactory failed, I got 413 error

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, http-status-code-413

Error Log:

```
For pattern: EMB5216_DO/DEVELOPER/SCTF/OUT/* 23 artifacts were found. 
17:32:52 Deploying artifact:http://192.168.5.2:9081/artifactory/LTEV5/SCTF/232/sctf_usdpaa_eth.so 
17:32:52 Deploying artifact:http://192.168.5.2:9081/artifactory/LTEV5/SCTF/232/framework.so 
17:32:52 Deploying artifact:http://192.168.5.2:9081/artifactory/LTEV5/SCTF/232/changefiles/HLPR_MP_changefiles.txt 
17:32:53 Deploying artifact:http://192.168.5.2:9081/artifactory/LTEV5/SCTF/232/sctf_om.so 
17:32:53 Deploying artifact: http://192.168.5.2:9081/artifactory/LTEV5/SCTF/232/sctf_dd_major.so 

Response received: <html> <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head> 17:32:53 <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.11.8</center> </body> </html> 

17:32:53 Failed while reading the response from: PUT http://192.168.5.2:9081/artifactory/LTEV5/SCTF/232/sctf_dd_major.so;vcs.revision=3f031a59068b91dfcc6647d44584f07a0c734f93;build.timestamp=1501665987574;build.name=LTEV5_SCTF;build.number=232 HTTP/1.1 
17:32:53 ERROR: remote file operation failed: /opt/workspace/LTEV5_SCTF at hudson.remoting.Channel@18021228:Channel to /192.168.5.101: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 413
```

there is no nginx server in ci system , cannot modify nginx.conf to resolve this question.

*jenkins version:2.46.2* 
*artifactory plugin version:2.12.2*
*artifactory-oss version:4.14*

thanks a lot

Comment: The response is clearly returned from NginX (nginx/1.11.8). You probably have an NginX in front of Artifactory which serves as an HTTP proxy. You should configure NginX as recommended in the answer by @arifCee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you check how large your biggest artifact is?

**Your nginx application sever doesn't accept files that exceed a certain file size.**

Have a look at your nginx configurations. This article might help you: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/.

Comment: default config(10240MB)

Comment: there is no nginx server in my ci system, so ??

Comment: in jenkins "system setting" --> "plugins manage" --> "advance" ，clear proxy settings, the problem gone~~

Answer (score 1):

**client_max_body_size** is not always the issue for **413** exception in Jenkins while pushing the images to artifactory.

When running Artifactory with Tomcat please check for **Enable Quota Control** option if it is checked and the storage quota has crossed the defined storage limit in that case you may get **413** as the status code.[image]